Editing multiple text files in Notepad++, how do I add an ending to all lines that begin with a certain word?
I am editing multiple text files at once in Notepad++. These are music lyric files. What I want it to do, for instance, is find all lines (in all files) that begin with the string: "[Artist:". I then want to add to the end of any line that begins as such an closing bracket: "]".
I've looked at a few other posts dealing with related problems and haven't been successful yet at translating their advice to my specific case. I can provide more details as needed to answer the question further.

What if there's already a ] on the end of the line?

A simple regex to do what you want is to replace ^(\[Artist:.*)$ with \1]. This adds a ] at the end of every line.
To avoid adding a ] to lines that already have it at the end, change the regex to search for ^(\[Artist:.*[^\]\r\n])$.
Explanation:
^             Start of line
(             Capture group
    \[        A single `[`
    Artist:   The characters themselves
    .*        Zero or more of any character
    [^\]\r\n] Character class, any character that is not `]`, CR or LF
)             End of capture
$             End of line

Note
If the character class is simple [^\]] and single-character line endings (e.g. just a LF as in Linux etc) then the capture would include the LF and the ] would be put on the next line. If two-character line endings (e.g. CRLF as in Windows) then there are two characters that the . does not match before the $ for end of line. Thanks to @Toto for noticing this problem. The fix is to also exclude CR and LF in the character class.

Note: This will put the ] on the next line if it is empty. It's better to use [^]\r\n] Demo

@Toto I have just tried the text from your demo in Notepad++ version 8.6.5 and I do not get the same effect. With Windows (i.e. CRLF) line endings the ] is added where I expected, not on the next line. I changed to Linux (i.e. LF only) line endings and get the effect you show. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Yes, in fact, it works with CRLF. That's really strange!
